# What's an elegant single word for "A new beginning" or "Fresh start"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

What's an elegant single word for "a new beginning" or "a fresh start"?

A good example would be a ceo of a company just filed chapter 11,  writes in an email

> We are looking to restructure our company … Looking forward for a ________ with our enterprise transformed into a cutting edge hi-tech...

Comment: Please add a sentence with a blank where you would put the word.

Comment: If the company was experiencing serious difficulties, consider "resurrection"

Comment: *transform* is a great word, i’d rewrite to use it in the blank: “Restructuring will allow us to transform our company into  a cutting-edge hi-tech...”

Comment: Define *elegant*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Renaissance](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/renaissance)** is elegant:

> (lowercase) a renewal of life, vigor, interest, etc.; rebirth; revival:
>   *a moral renaissance.*
>   (Dictionary.com)

Thus

> We are looking to restructure our company.... Looking forward to the **renaissance** of our Enterprise as a cutting edge hi-tech...

Comment: It's also hackneyed and doesn't really fit the context.

Answer (score 2):

How about **rebirth**?

OD:

> [**rebirth**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rebirth): A period of new life, growth, or activity; a
>   revival.
>   *‘the rebirth of a defeated nation’*

Answer (score 1):

Genesis

Meaning "New Beginning"

Comment: The questioner needs a 're-genesis', perhaps! Because it is a 'restructuring' rather than a first beginning.

Comment: I agree with @Jelila:  *genesis* usually implies the beginning of something that did not exist before, so it wouldn't be appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

***Reincarnation***, explained by [Wikipedia](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=Reincarnation):

> Reincarnation is the philosophical or religious concept that an aspect
>   of a living being starts a new life in a different physical body or
>   form after each biological death. It is also called rebirth or
>   transmigration, and is a part of the Saṃsāra doctrine of cyclic
>   existence.

The Supreme Court ruled that corporations are persons in some ways; [See When did Companies become People...](http://www.npr.org/2014/07/28/335288388/when-did-companies-become-people-excavating-the-legal-evolution), Nina Totenberg on NPR.

Reincarnation can be used for ideas or inamimate objects.  [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/reincarnation):

> A reappearance or revitalization in another form; a new embodiment:
>   "The brownstone had already endured one reincarnation: In the 1940's,
>   it was converted into eight studio apartments" (Ben Lloyd).